# How do you remove all elements from a repeated Proto field in Python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

Suppose I have the `.proto` file:

```proto
message Bar { }

message Foo {
  repeated Bar bars = 1;
}
```

How can you delete all of the elements in the field `bar`?

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of `del` and `[:]`:

```py
del foo.bars[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foo.ClearField('bars')` or `del foo.bars[:]`.